# How to check model values in View Model from Javascript in MVC4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to check that a Model value is NULL or NOT NULL in my view model in JavaScript, using mvc4.

How would I check this?

How do I get the values from my Model in JavaScript in the View model?

Answer (score 2):

There may be two way

first

```
@{
    string property = "";

    property = Model.Property == null ? "null value" : "value";
    // OR another comparison strategy
    ...
}

<script type="javascript">
   var property = @(property);
</script>
```

second

```
<script type="javascript">
  var property = @(Model.Property == null ? "null value" : "value");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will send a model's property from MVC to JS (views with Razor syntax):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var property = @Model.Property;
</script>
```

Old syntax will be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var property = <%=Model.Property%>;
</script>
```